# Unit Test principle

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Hi guys I'm start learning Unit Test or TDD .

I had some experience on C# so I was start with follow link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264975.aspx

follow the sample , so far so good.

But when I start first method by myself ,

I had some questions .

I wrote a method named "Log"

it will create a .txt file with timestamp

for example , after I called Log("some thing error");

it will created a file 201510210030.txt

the content is "[2015-10-21 00:30:47] some thing error"

How do I test it ?

may I read the log file ?

But every time I change the file name,

Maybe I will change the fold postion on the other situation.

Or maybe I will change log to DB or some logger server (with IoC)

How do I test it ? connect to DB or logger server ? read the file ?

It too much possible if the method fail(DB shut down or file auth fail balabala).

It not really "Unit" enough , so ... how do I test a method like this ,

Or just some concept I do not understand with Unit Test .

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With unit testing (as with all things), you need to be pragmatic. It's always great to aim for the 100% code coverage bench mark, but that's often-times unrealistic. The moment you start introducing actual databases or file systems into your tests, you've left the realm of unit tests and entered integration testing. There's absolutely nothing wrong with integration testing, but it's important not to confuse the two.

What I would recommend is to make sure you have all the logging logic in it's own separate class that is provided to the class you're testing via dependency injection (you mentioned IoC, so I assume you're familiar). Once you do that, you can pass in a mock "Logger" into your class that doesn't touch the file system at all. This will ensure that the class you're testing will handle anything that implements that "Logger"'s interface.

If you're looking to actually unit test the logger itself, then I'm afraid that's not really possible. The logger is very tightly coupled to the file system (or database), and so you can't really unit test it. You can always extract all the persistence logic to another class and mock that out, but you've only pushed the problem back. There's always a wall you'll come up against between your application and infrastructure, where the two are tightly coupled. The important thing is to keep the class that handles that interaction relatively simple, and make sure it's tested with integration tests.